# Hawtio WAR . local tab not appearing

Tags: activemq-classic, hawtio, jolokia

I have installed hawtio to control a activemq queue . I have used the chrome extension . When I connect I don't get the local tab . I receive a message saying to me ...

'The Local Tab is not currently enabled because either the server side hawtio-local-jvm-mbean plugin is not installed or this JVM cannot find the com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine API usually found in the tool.jar.'

So , I have download the war of jolokia agent and put in the same tomcat, getting as response of "localhost:8080/jolokia" a JSON text .

Even, I have check that I have 'tool.jar' in %JAVA_HOME%/lib (that is jdk1.7.0_45). I don't know why that's happening because as I see, I fullfill both requisites. The jconsole command shows the java processes.

Comment: Ok ... I have downloaded the version 1.2.0 and I have been able to run the app via localhost:8183/hawtio . The project I have it deployed in localhost:8080 , and I can do the connection, but I don't see any queue in ActiveMq dashboard, even I know my app uses an activmq queue.

Comment: Could you please explain me better the fields to make the remote connection ? I don't understand quite well the field 'path' and the field 'port' . Why 8161 ? . My queue is embedded . Should be 8080 ? . And the path ? Which path is it ? . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Path is the context where jolokia is handling requests, can't recall how it's configured in ActiveMQ but by default it's /jolokia, so you'd put "jolokia" in that field without the '/' at the beginning.  Port is the target port that's listening for HTTP requests.  If you've configured Jetty in ActiveMQ to listen on 8080 then set it to 8080.

Answer (score 0):

The local tab would not work in the google chrome extension as that is not allowed as an chrome app. But jolokia 1.2.x onwards support discovery out of the box, so if you use that version of jolokia, and hawtio 1.3.0 then there is a new discover tab that allows to discover what jolokia apps are in your network and connect to them with a single click.

For the current hawtio you can always use the remote tab, and fill in the details of url, port, credentials and connect.

I wrote a blog entry how to use the remote connect tab

- http://www.davsclaus.com/2014/01/hawtio-connecting-to-remote-activemq.html

.. its just with the remote tab there is fair number of details to enter and *get right*.

Comment: Ok, sorry but I'm quite newbie . I'm getting 'connection refuse' always. I'll explain myself better . 

I had an embedded activeMq queue in localhost:8080 . I'm running a war of jolokia called 'jolokia.war' in the same tomcat server, so I use localhost:8080/jolokia to retieve the json and see that is working . Last, but not least, I have raised my hawtio via 'java -jar hawtio-app-1.2.0.jar' -p 8183 ( I can't use the port 8080 because it's used by the application ) .

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that I did more or less same comment above and here, under the comment . Just didn't notice